# How do I make a valid browser redirect at the end of a controller request hit via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I make an ajax request to the following controller method:

```
def destroy
    ...
    redirect_to "/courses"
end
```

The console shows the redirection and rendering work, but the browser does not actually load the page (presumably because the request was made by ajax rather than standard HTTP).  I want to actually have the browser load the `/courses` page, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would send the redirect from your client-side JavaScript in a **location.href** like so:

```
$.ajax("/destroy")
  .done(function() {
    location.href="/courses";
  });
```

I don't know what library you use for your ajax calls, so I just used jQuery syntax.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change your route to destroy.js rather than destroy. It will make rails render a js template instead of a html template.

```
= link_to 'Destroy', course_path(@course_id), method: :destroy, format: :js
```

Then, create a destroy.js.erb (or haml if that's what you're using) and add the javascript code there:

```
window.location.href = '/courses';
```

You should be considering why use ajax at all if you're redirecting the user browser anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

**Response**

The bottom line is that you can't redirect from an ajax request - you'll have to accommodate the redirect in the *response*

Ajax basically sends a "pseudo-request" to your app's backend. This request is best described as being quite "dumb" - it can only process a response directly from the initiated request (nothing more); which means that if you want to handle a redirect, you'll need to deal with it in your browser end.

I'd be looking at doing this:

```
#app/controllers/courses_controller.rb
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, only: :destroy

   def destroy
      @course = Course.find params[:id]
      @course.destroy
   end
end

#app/views/courses/destroy.js.erb
window.location.assign("<%=j courses_index_path %>");
```

This will be the most effective way of proessing the "redirect". It won't be a redirect at all - just JS reloading your page based on a specifically-timed JS call!!